# Karatsuba Multiplication with Strings C++

Tags: c++, c++11

I am struggling to get the correct output for my Karatsuba multiplication using strings.
I am inputting numbers in the format: int1 int2 base, where int1 and int2 are the numbers to be multiplied, and base is the numerical base.

My output is in the format add mult, where add represents the "School Method Addition" of int1 and int2 and mult represents the Karatsuba multiplication.

For INPUT:

```
1231000323012031333233201313312322110321130022201222133322033312000313333113222010300133031211311 10203302031023112301210030203002033323 4
```

I should get the OUTPUT:

```
1231000323012031333233201313312322110321130022201222133322110121303011022232123220331002033311300 
490306232475117580392628428529303475424922697851904379576867313243824589283681700912220831308362948505562812188832489817917769878090
```

I am unsure what's going wrong, any help would be appreciated.

Below is my code:

```
// The main function that adds two bit sequences and returns the addition

string add_strings(string a, string b){

    string result ;  // To store the sum bits
 
    // make the lengths same before adding
    int length = max(a.length(), b.length()) ;
    while (a.length() < length) a.insert(0, "0") ;
    while (b.length() < length) b.insert(0, "0") ;

    // Initialize carry
    int carry = 0 ;
 
    // Add all bits one by one
    for (int i = length - 1 ; i > -1 ; i--)
    {
        int aBit = a[i] - '0' ;
        int bBit = b[i] - '0' ;
 
        // Boolean expression for sum of 3 bits
        int sum = aBit + bBit + carry ;

        // Update carry
        carry = sum / base ;

        // Update sum for string insertion
        sum = sum % base ;
 
        // Update sum result
        result.insert(0, to_string(sum)) ;
    }
 
    // if overflow, then add the carry
    if (carry)  result.insert(0, to_string(carry)) ;

    return result.erase(0, min(result.find_first_not_of('0'), result.size() - 1)) ;
}

// Function for find difference of larger numbers

string sub_strings(string a, string b, int base)
{
    // Ensure the first string is bigger than the second
    // Therefore no negative cases, no carry needed
    int comp = a.compare(b) ;
    if (comp < 0) swap(a, b) ;

    // Make the lengths same before subtracting
    int length = max(a.length(), b.length()) ;
    while (a.length() < length) a.insert(0, "0") ;
    while (b.length() < length) b.insert(0, "0") ;
 
    // Initialise result string
    string result = "";
    int diff, carry ;
 
    // Subtraction
    for (int i = length - 1; i > -1; i--) {
 
        // Find difference of each digit
        int aBit = a[i] - '0' ;

        int bBit = b[i] - '0' ;

        diff = (aBit - bBit) / base ;

        result.insert(0, to_string(diff)) ;
     }
 
    // reverse resultant string
    reverse(result.begin(), result.end());
 
    return result.erase(0, min(result.find_first_not_of('0'), result.size() - 1)) ; 
}
```

UPDATE:
I added a shift left function to ensure everything is multiplied by the base:

void leftShift(string &ab, int k){

```
reverse(ab.begin(), ab.begin() + 1) ;
reverse(ab.begin() + 1, ab.end()) ;
reverse(ab.begin(), ab.end()) ;
```

}

Here is my updated Karatsuba:

string Karatsuba(string a, string b, int base){

```
// Base cases
int length = max(a.length(), b.length());
if (length == 0) return 0 ;
if (length == 1) return to_string((a[0] - '0')*(b[0] - '0')) ;

// Add leading zeros to ensure numbers are the same size
while (a.length() < length) a.insert(0, "0") ;
while (b.length() < length) b.insert(0, "0") ;

// Split a into (a0, a1) and b into (b0, b1)
int k = length / 2 ;
int upper = length - k ;

// convert the above vectors to strings for multiplication
// need separate for loops to prevent out of range errors
string a0 = a.substr(k) ;
string a1 = a.substr(0, upper) ;
string b0 = b.substr(k) ;
string b1 = b.substr(0, upper) ;

// Compute the three products
// p0 = a0b0, p1 = (a1+a0)*(b1+b0), p2 = a1b1
string p0 = Karatsuba(a0, b0, base) ;
string p1 = Karatsuba(add_strings(a1, a0, base), add_strings(b1, b0, base), base) ;
string p2 = Karatsuba(a1, b1, base) ;

//ab = p2 * (pow(base, 2*k)) + (p1 - (p2 + p0)) * pow(base, k) + p0
// term1 = p2 * (pow(base, 2*k))
// term2 = (p1 - (p2 + p0)) * pow(base, k)
string term2 = sub_strings(add_strings(p2, p0, base), p1, base) ;
leftShift(p2, k) ;
leftShift(p2, k) ;
leftShift(term2, k) ;

// term3 = p0

// Add leading zeros
for (int i = 0; i < upper; i++) p0.append("0") ;
for (int i = 0; i < upper; i++) term2.append("0") ;
    
string result = add_strings(add_strings(p2, p0, base), term2, base) ;

return result.erase(0, min(result.find_first_not_of('0'), result.size() - 1));
```

}

Comment: c and c++ are separate languages, please don't tag both unless you are actually using both. What is the output of your code? Have you tried using a debugger?

Comment: I suggest you use, say, 6-byte strings in the debugging phase, not 97-byte strings. Then you can do the computations by hand and compare them with the results of your code.

Comment: Why is the expected output not in base 4 when the input was base 4? And why does your code have a bunch of `/ 10` and `% 10` which indicates that it's specific to base 10?

Comment: That's a lot of code to debug and review. The first smell I see is the use of floating point in floor and ceil. `int k = length/2;` would already round down, and `int upper = length - k;` would give you the rest without resorting to floating point maths.

Comment: the output seems as you expect other than missing the last digit? https://godbolt.org/z/GP1nKfd8P

Comment: Looking at your code, you aren't doing anything at all with `base`.

Comment: Hi, You're not using `base`. The best way to debug recursive calls is to start small. Try multiplying small numbers (say 1 - 5 digits) before going into the big cases you're trying, You usually find the error more easily at small scale.

Answer (score 0):

First, implement naive addition.  Write unit tests.

Next, implement naive multiplication.  Write unit tests.

Next, implement fancy multiplication.  You should pass a verifier in as an optional parameter.  Verify each sub multiplication with the naive one.  On failureblog what input generates what wrong output.

Add that to the unit test cases.

Use this to generate a tiny error case, no longer than 6 to 8 digits.